# Doing LOS Analysis using QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am not able to do LOS analysis in QGIS. I have point Features and Raster SRTM Data. I have installed the LOS Plugin in QGIS but I am not getting any results.

Comment: Welcome to GIS@SE. Perhaps you are more likely to get an answer if you describe what you have tried already, what plugins you use, etc. It is a big help if you ask specific questions with examples of what you have already tried, rather than a broad question ..

Comment: Have you try to use the r.los GRASS algorithm in the processor?